# Vaguely Remembered Creepy Book Cover of YA Sci-Fi/Horror Story circa 2000

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror, cover-art

I suddenly remembered the creepy cover of a book I saw in a children's/young adult bookstore as a kid around the year 2000.

It looked too scary so I didn't buy it.

Here is all I remember:

The cover had three or so hideous fish-like or frog-like people in a swamp.

The blurb on the back described a female character coming into contact with people with "big eyes and fat heads."

Thinking back on it, the plot seems inspired by *the Shadow over Innsmouth*, which I didn't know about at the time, but the writing on the back was not in Lovecraft's style.

I seem to remember it was part of a series, and that the cover of another book in the series had a xenomorph-like creature in front of a desert landscape dotted with metallic tanks (containers not vehicles).

Does anyone have any idea what this might be?

Comment: What do you remember about the plot that reminds you of the Shadow Over Innsmouth, or was it just the general idea of the frog creatures?

Comment: Honorable mention for the [many various covers](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+moon+pool%22+merritt&hl=en&gbv=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch) of *The Moon Pool* by A. Merritt which have many renderings of creepy frog people, and a female character in contact with them.

Comment: @Vanguard3000 I think the blurb talked about the people from a certain town being froglike, and they might have been related to the main character girl in some way...something like "so-and-so's relatives down in such-and-such a place looked strange - big eyes. Fat heads." In that sense it seemed like Innsmouth, but I don't know what the actual plot was, and my memory might be mixed up

Comment: @Lexible That looks cool! But in my mind's eye, the cover does not feature the contacting female (just the frog monsters) and looks to have been made with a modern imaging editor like Photoshop. Also, the back blurb was written in a contemporary style, which makes me think it was perhaps inspired by stories like the Moon Pool rather than being a reprinting

Comment: Hence, "honorable mention." :) But your should edit your question with the points you just commented on (e.g., Photoshopped, etc).